# WordPress SSO - Azure AD B2C - Sign up and sign in User Flow - How to link directly to registration page?

Tags: wordpress, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to setup a single sign on system using WordPress and Azure AD B2C. I’ve got it working, however, I’m trying to find a way that would allow me to link to the registration page on Azure directly. Currently, I’m only able to generate a link to the Sign-on page. I’d like to find a way to generate a link to the Sign-up page. I’m using the Sign up and sign in User Flow, and due to the way the WordPress Plugin was developed, I can’t use more than this one user flow.

I've written a script that looks at the source of the Sign on page, grabs the sign-up link and displays it, but that approach doesn’t work.

I need to be able to display both Sign-on and Sign-up links on my website.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to where and how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one user flow, it's not possible to achieve this. You cannot link to the Sign Up portion of the combined flow. You have to go through the Sign In page to reach the Sign Up page.